# Phinx seeds won't run after upgrade to php7.0

Tags: php, migration, database-migration, phinx

I have a bunch of Phinx seeds which used to run fine

```
php vendor/bin/phinx seed:run
```

My seeds are located in `var/www/html/db/seeds` folder

I recently upgraded my VM to php 7.0 (Also upgraded to 16.04 LTS box), now I get the following output & error when I try to run phinx seeds:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/var/www/html$ sudo vendor/bin/phinx seed:run
Phinx by Rob Morgan - https://phinx.org. version 0.5.4

using config file ./phinx.yml
using config parser yaml
using migration path /var/www/html/db/migrations
using seed path /var/www/html/db/seeds
warning no environment specified, defaulting to: development
using adapter mysql
using database closecall

[InvalidArgumentException]        
The seed class "" does not exist
```

To reiterate, seeds were running fine, upgraded to php 7.0 and now they're not.

Migrations still run completely fine, however.

I've removed all seeds bar one:

```
<?php

use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

class CategorySeeder extends AbstractSeed
{
    public function run()
    {
        $data = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Confined Spaces'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

To debug with, still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php vendor/bin/phinx seed:run -s CategorySeeder
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `void` as a return type and it should work as expected w/ PHP 7+.

```
<?php

use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

class CategorySeeder extends AbstractSeed
{    
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $data = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Confined Spaces'
            )
        );
    }
}
```